# What does this code do?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
int mystery(int x, int n)
{
   return (x + (x>>31 & ((1 << n) + ~0))) >> n;
}
```

I have been trying to figure out how this  code works. This is what I have so far:

- shifts n left over one,
- adds that result to 1^32 (why?)
- ands this result to x shifted over to 31 (wouldn't this just clear the value of x>>31?)
- and right before it shifts by n, adds x (again, I don't understand why)

Comment: It might be interesting to see what the type of the x and n variables is.

Comment: how are x and n defined? 32b or 64b?

Comment: if `x` is an `int32`, then `x>>31` returns `1` if the number is negative and `0` if it is `0` or positive.

Comment: It might also be interesting to know what the return type of the function is. In any case, this coding style should be forbidden in any professional project.

Comment: Also, `(1 << n) + ~0` translates into `2^n - 1`. Or, what is the same, `1`s in the `n-1` least significative positions.

Comment: Please specify the exact types on `x` and `n` (width, signed/unsigned etc).

Comment: @SirDarius they are type ints

Comment: @NPE they are type ints and the return is type int

Comment: I added the surrounding function definition code that was missing, based on comments. What is the name of the function? That *could* provide a clue, unless it was designed to be opaque.

Comment: @SJuan76: You make a wrong assumption. If x is signed then `x >> 31` will be 0 if x >= 0, -1 if x < 0. Most implementations implement right shift as arithmetic when x is signed and logical when x is unsigned

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc ok I forgot that, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It divides by 2^n with correct rounding (round towards zero) so that the expression is equivalent to:

y = x / (1 << n);

If you take a naïve approach to division by 2^n, i.e.

```
y = x >> n;
```

you get incorrect rounding for x < 0.

This part of the expression: `(x>>31 & ((1 << n) + ~0))` is equal to zero for x >= 0, but for x < 0 it adjusts the result appropriately by adding 2^n - 1.

Note that strictly speaking the expression relies on implementation-specific behaviour, as it assumes that right shifting a signed integer preserves the sign bit. While this is true for most compilers and platforms, it can not be guaranteed, so the expression is not 100% safe or portable.

Note also that the expression has a hard-coded assumption that int is 32 bits, which also makes it non-portable. A more portable version which works with any size of int would be:

```
   return (x + (x >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) & ((1 << n) + ~0))) >> n;
```

Comment: I tried it and I got 0..Never thought of `x<0`..Nice ans...+1

Comment: OP says the return type and type of variables is `int`. Does this work the same in environments where int is 64 bits ?

Comment: No - it's assuming 32 bit ints (i.e. int32_t). It wouldn't be hard to make it more general however - I've updated the answer with a more portable version.